# Power BI - Running total with a specific Start Value

Tags: powerbi, dax, cumulative-sum

I hope someone can help me with this. It's probably pretty simple for some of you:-).

I have created a running total in Power BI to show my cash flow and it works well. Now, when I include a measure called "cash injection" as the starting value, the running total only shows the cash injection value throughout the entire time period instead of just today's date.
(Side note: The measure "cash injection" is adjustable using a slicer.)

Below is my running total formula which works, but when I add my measure (cash injection ($)) I run into the issue. FYI: there is no relationship between Append and Cash injection

Thank you!

```
Total Due ($) running total in Day =
[Cash injection ($)]
    + CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Append1'[Total Due ($)] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLSELECTED ( 'Rolling_Calendar'[Date].[Day] ),
            ISONORAFTER (
                    'Rolling_Calendar'[Date].[Day],
                    MAX ( 'Rolling_Calendar'[Date].[Day] ),
                    DESC
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: I am assuming [Cash Injection] and [Total Due ($) running total in Day] are measures and you are filtering by Dates? Is there an active relationship between Cash Injection's table and the Dates table?

Comment: Hi  AntrikshSharma, I just created a relationship between the dates and cash injection but I still run into the same issue.

Comment: Can you please share some sample data?

Comment: Yes, but how do I attach files / screenshots in this thread?

Comment: Maybe this will help in the meantime. The cash flow file is created by importing 3 different excel files and then I append them. In the append file the column Total Due ($) is the value I use in the matrix. To calculate “cash injection” I use List.Numbers(0,301,10000) so my total in the matrix is over $400 million instead of $3,000,000. My goal is simply to have a slicer between 0-$3,000,000. In below example I show the cash injection at $100 for simplicity.

Cash Flow 10-May 11-May

Cash injection 100

AR 10 10

AP -8 -8

Other charges -1 -1

Total 101 1